# Atomic Boolean lattice is weakly atomic

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

The book "Introduction to Lattices and Order" says at Exercise 10.12 that an atomic Boolean lattice is weakly atomic.

Could you tell me why it holds?

Comment: What is the definition of weakly atomic? Where to read about this (online)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be our atomic Boolean lattice, and suppose $x, y \in L$ with $x < y$. We have to show that there exist $a,b \in L$ such that $x \leq a \prec b \leq y$.

Let $x'$ denote the complement of $x$, and consider the homomorphism
\begin{align*}
\downarrow x' &\longrightarrow \uparrow x, \\
c &\longmapsto c \vee x
\end{align*}
which is easily seen to be an isomorphism of lattices with inverse $d \mapsto d \wedge x'$. Now $\downarrow x'$ inherits atomicity from $L$, so $\uparrow x$ is atomic as well. Since $x < y$, there exists an $a \in \uparrow x$ such that $x \prec a \leq y$.

Comment: I take it that $\prec$ is the covering (immediate successor) relation?

Comment: Yes. I use the notation of the book referred to in the question, so $\prec$ is the covering relation, $\downarrow x = \{ a \in L : a \leq x \}$ and similarly for $\uparrow x$.

Comment: Thanks. I was familiar with the arrow notations, but I was inferring the other from context. (+1)